# How do I run a Java application from the command line when it is in a package?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [package in .java file makes class file unuseable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868506/package-in-java-file-makes-class-file-unuseable)

My Hellow World runs fine.
But as soon as I add a package reference I cannot run it from the command line:

```
package pv;
public class hcw2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Cruel World.");
    }
}
```

compiles fine, then I expect to use java pv.hcw2 to run it, as:

```
>java pv.hcw2
>Error: Could not find or load main class pv.hcw2
```

I have also tried just java hcw2, to no avail.

Running in the same directory as the original which runs. Running on Windows 7 64b.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should have a folder called pv under which your file hcw2.java should lie. The folder pv is nothing but your package. Then outside the directory you may issue a javac command as shown below followed by java.

```
braga@braga-laptop:~$ javac pv/hcw2.java 

braga@braga-laptop:~$ ls pv
hcw2.class  hcw2.java

braga@braga-laptop:~$ java pv.hcw2 
Hello Cruel World.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep your class in the folder named your package. so for :

```
 package pv;
    public class hcw2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello Cruel World.");
        }
    }
```

The hcw2.java should be kept like `pv\hcw2.java` 
once you compile successfully there should be the class file in same folder like :

```
pv\hcw2.class
```

While running you have to change directory to the base directory. so if your directory structure like : `d:\java\pv\hcw2.java` 
then 
Change dir to d:\java>

```
Run the java command there with the package name. So : 
d:\java> java pv/hcw2 or
```

D:\java>java test.Test

Answer (score 0):

Your java class needs to be inside a subdirectory called pv.  So:

> mkdir pv
>
> mv hcw2.java hcw2.class pv

then you can run

> java pv.hcw2

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was sure it was something simple! : -)